# Wordpress - Form to match registered users

Tags: wordpress

I need to create a form on wordpress for registered users.
Users don't have to reach backend but they land on a page with just a form where they write their email and submit.
If the mail matches with the mail registered as user they'll be redirected to the next page.
If there's no matching mail on user list they just receive an error to try again.

It's for a kind of browser game...

Thanks

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Am confused!

Comment: i want to create a form where you write an email address. if that address is on wordpress user list you'll be redirected on next page. If no wordpress users have that mail you have to retry.

Answer (score 1):

For checking whether an email exists or not, you can use the `email_exists()` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/email_exists/) provided by WordPress.

Here's the example:

```
$email = 'myemail@example.com';
$exists = email_exists( $email );
if ( $exists ) {
    echo "That E-mail is registered to user number " . $exists;
} else {
    echo "That E-mail doesn't belong to any registered users on this site";
}
```

You can use it to define your logic.

---

And for redirection, WordPress has a [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) called `wp_redirect()`

Here's an exammple:

```
wp_redirect( 'http://www.mynewurl.com/blah/' ); exit;
```

Make sure to call `exit` just after calling that function.

---

And if you are having trouble figuring out how to know whether the user is actually a logged in user or not, you can use the `is_user_logged_in()` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/).

Here's an example:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, guest!';
}
```

Now you got all the functions needed to complete your task! Just make use of these functions properly based on your logic and you will be able to complete it!